# Aligning items to right in navbar with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am trying to right align some elements in the navbar using bootstrap by using mr-auto but it is not working. What should I do to make it work correctly?
This is my index.html code.

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="favicon-16x16.png">
  <link rel="manifest" href="site.webmanifest">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Silicon</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid ">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img src="logo.png" alt="" width="200" height="83" class="d-inline-block align-text-top">

          </a>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav  mb-2 mb-lg-0 ml-auto">     */here i used ml-auto for margin*/           
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
              Dropdown
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li>
                <hr class="dropdown-divider">
              </li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

</body>

</html>
```

In bootstrap documentation, it says you should you ml-auto for margin on left and mr-auto for margin on right. But it is not working here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since version 5, `ml-auto` is not in Bootstrap anymore... Use new syntax instead:

```
ml-auto => ms-auto (start)
mr-auto => me-auto (end)
```